# Most closest value to database entry in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table field with the actually size of an apartment, like 55.74, 66.27, 80.43 ...

In the search for a suitable record I want to get a list of records that are ordered by closest to that value. If the user enter in the search field e.g. 65, then the order of the records would be:
66.27 (difference of 1.27)
55.74 (difference of 9.26)
80.43 (difference of 14.43)

What is the best approach to find this order?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your orderby clause to be a new column, in this case something like

```
orderby ABS(BlockSize - SearchValue) asc
```

The ABS() function making all negatives become positives, so your order then adjusts on the total difference between the original size and the searchvalue

i.e.

```
Block Sizes | Search Value | Order Column
500 | 200 | 300
100 | 200 | 100
300 | 200 | 100
200 | 200 | 0
```

So for the above showing if your search value is 200, it would set the Order Column to be the total difference of numbers in ascending order (or in this case 200, 100, 300, 500)

Answer (score 0):

It can achieved as below:

```
  select  ABS(colname-65) as t
  FROM table name
  Order by ABS(colname-65)
```

Comment: While the ORDER BY clause is correct, obviously the rest of this example query is wrong

Comment: @Strawberry, On what basis you are saying that query is wrong?

Comment: Well it's just that the result of such a query wouldn't be much use to any one

Comment: As OP didn't mention what he wants as a result, so I have provided the sample query for the same... OP can add whatever columns he wants in the select

Comment: Well, the op wants the nearest result to a given value.